# wordpress upload logo not work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I follow up the [sitepoint tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-wordpress-theme-settings-page-with-the-settings-api/) to create logo uploader for my option page but the image uploader not working correctly.

here the **functions.php**:

```
function logo_display()
{
    ?>
        <input type="file" name="logo" /> 
        <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
   <?php
}

function handle_logo_upload()
{
    if(!empty($_FILES["demo-file"]["tmp_name"]))
    {
        $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["logo"], array('test_form' => FALSE));
        $temp = $urls["url"];
        return $temp;   
    }

    return $option;
}

function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
    add_settings_section("section", "All Settings", null, "theme-options");

    add_settings_field("logo", "Logo", "logo_display", "theme-options", "section");  

    register_setting("section", "logo", "handle_logo_upload");
}

add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you view source, you will prob see the enctype is not set to enctype="multipart/form-data". You could do something like below to change the enctype

```
function change_form_enc() {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                      jQuery('form').attr('enctype','multipart/form-data');
                  });
              </script>";
}



if ( is_admin() ) {

    add_action('admin_head', 'change_form_enc');
}
```

Comment: i just add your code in `function.php` but unfortunately not work. also add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload form. but not work         `<input type="file" name="logo" enctype="multipart/form-data" /> `

Comment: can you view source and see if the enc type has changed for the form (its not required for the input type) also is your logo nested within form tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
function logo_display()
{
    ?>
        <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" /> 
        <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
   <?php
}

function handle_logo_upload()
{
    if(!empty($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"]))
    {
        $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["logo"], array('test_form' => FALSE));
        if ($urls["error"]) 
        {
            return $urls["error"];
        }
        $temp = $urls["url"];
        return $temp;   
    } 
    return get_option('logo');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide information of what changes you consider are needed in order to solve the asker question instead of **just** posting code.